# Cucumber command not found

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

While executing my feature file,in the local Jenkins I am getting the below error.

> cucumber: command not found

I am using cucumber feature/xyz.feature  command to run the scripts

Any pointers how to proceed.

Comment: Please provide the error log exactly.

Comment: if you go into the directory on the slave where it failed, does the cucumber program work? it may be a PATH issue, but it might just be that this program isn't installed. are you using ruby or java?

Comment: I am using Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should be able to run the cucumber executable if the setup is done correctly. Read [here](http://www.agiletrailblazers.com/blog/the-5-step-guide-for-selenium-cucumber-and-gherkin).

From the error it looks like cucumber is not on your path thus indicating RubyGems binary folder is not on your path. Check the path (use `gem env`) and update it accordingly.